# Setting a Path as an Environment Variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing a test suite for a Ruby on Rails application.  I'm testing a controller named "parser.rb" using the "`test_parser.rb`" test.  "`parser.rb`" is saved in the `app/controllers` folder while "test_parser.rb" is saved in `test/controllers`.  Right now, to use the "`parser.rb`" file, I include the following code:

```
require "test/unit"
$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path '../../../app/controllers',__FILE__ 
require "parser"
```

I would rather not have to set the load path in each test file.  I tried various Google searches for adding a load path globally, but the results focus on adding paths via the command line, or they talk about exporting environment variables without really explaining what that means.  What exactly does it mean to export an environment variable?  Does that even make sense in this context?  Ideally, I would like to include this as part of the test configurations - what changes do I have to make to which files (i.e., test_helper, environment/test/, config/environment, etc.)?

I'm on windows 8 but I run Ruby and Rails through Cygwin.

Comment: Setting an environment variable makes the name and value visible to the current shell. Exporting the environment variable makes the name and value inheritable by other (sub) shells.

Answer (score 0):

Since rails combined the ideas **auto loading** and **convention over configuration**, you don't have to require the controller class yourself, as long as your controller is in the `autoload_paths` (i.e. `app/controllers[/concerns]` and `app/models[/concerns]`) and the file name matches the class name in the rails way.

But if you have to manually require that file, try `require_relative` instead of `require`:

```
require 'test/unit'
require_relative '../../app/controllers/parser'
```

BTW, you should suffix your controller class name with `Controller` (e.g. `ParsersController`), otherwise you may have troubles with routing.

Comment: As Aetherus said, you should follow the name convention to enable auto loading. Try to rename the controller, `app/controllers/parses_controller.rb`, and its test `test/controllers/parses_controller_test.rb`, then you won't need to manually require.

Comment: Thanks! As it turns out, my parser should most likely be in the lib directory, as opposed to an actual controller - I knew there was something I was forgetting about the setup.  Thanks again.